# SQL Server column line break

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following line in a SQL query I want to add line break before `BookedBy` and `OrderNo`, any idea how do this?

```
,FromAddress=  LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(( case when (b.FromDoorNo is not NULL AND  b.FromDoorNo!='') then b.FromDoorNo + ' - '+ b.FromAddress else b.FromAddress END),'LONDON',''),'ROAD','RD'),'DRIVE','DR'),'AVENUE','AVE'),'GREENFORD',''),'LANE','LN')))

,ToAddress=LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(( case when (b.ToDoorNo is not NULL and b.ToDoorNo!='') then b.ToDoorNo + ' - '+ b.ToAddress else b.ToAddress END),'LONDON',''),'ROAD','RD'),'DRIVE','DR'),'AVENUE','AVE'),'GREENFORD',''),'LANE','LN')))
```

Your suggested query I enter below but its show result below, and also address shows null ;( if bookedby id null do not show bookedby and if orderno null not show  orderno, but always show address ;( where is the mistake in my query?

```
  ,FromAddress=  LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(( case when (b.FromDoorNo is not NULL AND  b.FromDoorNo!='') then b.FromDoorNo + ' - '+ b.FromAddress else b.FromAddress END),'LONDON',''),'ROAD','RD'),'DRIVE','DR'),'AVENUE','AVE'),'GREENFORD',''),'LANE','LN')))+ CHAR(13) +(CASE WHEN  b.BookedBy IS NOT NULL THEN 'BookedBy: ' +b.BookedBy else null end) + CHAR(13) +(CASE WHEN  b.OrderNo IS NOT NULL THEN 'OrderNo: ' + b.OrderNo else null end)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **CHAR(13)** where you wants to add new line/line break.

```
DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(500)='AB-ASDA233 - HEATHROW TERMINAL 4, TW6 2GA BookedBy: adeelcheck OrderNo: adeelorder'

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@Variable,'OrderNo:',CHAR(13) + 'OrderNo:'),'BookedBy:',CHAR(13) + 'BookedBy:')
```

**Final result will be:**

```
 AB-ASDA233 - HEATHROW TERMINAL 4, TW6 2GA 
 BookedBy: adeelcheck 
 OrderNo: adeelorder
```

Comment: AB-ASDA233 - HEATHROW TERMINAL 4, TW6 2GA BookedBy: adeelcheck OrderNo: adeelorder not show full line ;(

Comment: at which step you need break line?

Comment: i want bookedby in new line and orderno in new line

Comment: To see effect of result, copy executed result and paste in somewhere else

Comment: You can get accepted result from any column, I have just give you an example

Comment: my sql case statement not perfect fine ;( is orderno is null full result are null